# how could set content-type in magento web api?

Tags: magento

I build simple web api and it returns  the error **"message": "Content-Type header is invalid."** how could I resolve it please guide me.
under Magento/SamplePaymentGateway/etc my webapi is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route method="GET" url="/V1/cevnn/post">
        <service class="Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Api\PostManagementInterface" method="getPost"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Magento/SamplePaymentGateway/Api is PostManagementInterface.php file

```
<?php
namespace Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Api;
interface PostManagementInterface {
    public function getPost($param);
}
```

and under Mangento/SamplePaymentGateway/Model there is PostManagement.php file

```
<?php
namespace Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Model;
class PostManagement {
    public function getPost($param)
    {
        return 'api GET return the $param ' . $param;
    }
}
```

when I call it through this url http://127.0.0.1/project-community-edition/rest/V1/cevnn/post?param=ali.
it returns the following error {
    "message": "Content-Type header is invalid."
}
please guide me how could I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection configuration is missing.

In order to tell Magento which class to use for interface `Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Api\PostManagementInterface`, you must add it in your `di.xml` file :

```
<preference for="Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Api\PostManagementInterface" type="Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Model\PostManagement"/>
```

Comment: I did it too. Sorry, I forgot to mention it above. it is not working in postman although it's working in web browser

Comment: Ok, so maybe problem comes from postman request. Can you post it in order to see if there is something wrong with it ?